# Jersey Restful exception

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I'm facing Jersey 2.7. This is my service:

```
package edu.srv.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@Path("/algebra")
public class Algebra extends Application {

    @GET
    @POST
    @Path("/sum")
    public int sum(@QueryParam("a") int a, @QueryParam("b") int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RS1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>edu.srv.rest.Algebra</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RS1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/algebra/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

when I try to deploy (tomcat 6, tomcat 7, tomcat 8) this service as war I got this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.model.ContractProvider$Builder
```

what am I missing?

Comment: How are you building the package?  You should inspect that actual artifact (WAR file, etc.) being built and verify that the correct JARs are actually making it in.

Comment: You are probably missing the jar with that class - http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.glassfish.jersey.model.ContractProvider%22.

Comment: Hello. I pack it as WAR, JARs in its WEB-INF/lib are exactly the ones shown in picture. org.glassfish.jersey.model.ContractProvider$Builder is in jersey-common.jar.

Comment: Are your JARs from lib directory really included in built WAR file? Check it (open it same as a ZIP archive).

Comment: @klimpond yes they are.

Comment: Interesting, next step I would try would be to copy your JAR to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have the jersey-common.jar file on my classpath and have confirmed that the file contains the org.glassfish.jersey.model.ContractProvider$Builder class, but I still get the NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 3):

`org.glassfish.jersey.model.ContractProvider$Builder` uses `javax.inject.Singleton` class which is present in `javax.inject` jar. Include the same to resolve the issue.