# Jersey Restful exception 1

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, classnotfound

full archive:
[google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1VlopsZOhqsczM3UHpYUGk1d2c/view?usp=sharing)

(Tomcat 7.0)

I have repeated the code from [Jersey Restful exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939248/jersey-restful-exception)

Local test URL - http://localhost:8080/test/algebra/sum?a=1&b=2

and got :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Resource configuration class edu.algebra could not be loaded.

type Exception report

message Resource configuration class edu.algebra could not be loaded.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource configuration class edu.algebra could not be loaded.
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:466)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:302)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:168)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
root cause

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.algebra**
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:407)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:397)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:454)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:302)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:168)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure is not correct. Java code should be in src folder, not class. Find one of million tutorials "Hello World web application on Tomcat" and follow it.
E.g. - http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/2/JSP-Hello-World-Program-using-Eclipse-IDE-and-Tomcat-web-server